# 非同期にしたrequestsの処理でタイムアウト時のエラーハンドリングをしたい。

Tags: python, python3, 非同期, python-requests

requestsを非同期にしたのですが、タイムアウト時のエラーハンドリングしたいです。

**プログラムで実行したい事**

[前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70112/python%E3%81%AErequests%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E9%9D%9E%E5%90%8C%E6%9C%9F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)欲しい商品を検索するプログラムを作成しました。
商品全体のページからurlsを取得して非同期でアクセスを出して欲しい商品とマッチする商品urlを取得するものです。

安定してプログラムが動作するように
サイトが重くなり読み込みが遅い場合にフリーズを避けるためにrequestsにタイムアウトの時間を設定しました。
もしタイムアウトでエラーが発生した場合は、一旦そこでタスク完了にして、エラーが出たurlをリストに格納して貯めます。
場合によって、検索に引っかかった：urlとアクセスできなかった：urlsが出来る。

１回目のイベントループによる仕事が終了した際、エラーが起きても、欲しい商品urlは見つかれば処理を終了します。
もし欲しいurlが見つからない場合は先ほど探せなかったurlsから再び探すためにイベントループに仕事を与えます。
これを再帰的に行うプログラムを書きたくて挑戦したのですが再帰呼びすぎとエラーが出て上手く動作しないです。

```
import asyncio
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

class Test():
    # initとあるがこれもあくまで最初のメソッドに過ぎないためJSのコンストラクタのように使用出来ない。
    def __init__(self):
        self.links = []

    def get_item_urls(self, category):
        url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/' + category
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                category_page = requests.get(url, timeout=(3.0, 7.5))
            except Timeout:
                print('カテゴリページ読み込めなかった。')
            else:
                break
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(category_page.content, 'lxml')
        items_div = soup.select('article > .inner-article > a')
        links = [url.get('href') for url in items_div]
        return links
    
    def search_item(self, link, name, color):
        url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com' + link
        try:
            item_page = requests.get(url, timeout=(3.0, 7.5))
        except Timeout:
            print('商品ページがひらけない')
            return url
        soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page.content, 'lxml')
        item_name = soup.select('h1[itemprop="name"]')[0].string
        print(item_name)
        item_color = soup.select('#details > p.style')[0].string
        print(item_color)
        if name in item_name and color in item_color:
            return url

    def non_req_url(self, category, name, color):
        async def want_item_url(loop, links, name, color):
            sem = asyncio.Semaphore(20)
            async def async_ex(i):
                async with sem:
                    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.search_item, links[i], name, color)
            tasks = [async_ex(i) for i in range(len(links))]
            return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        links = self.get_item_urls(category)
        def do_task(links, name, color):
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = loop.run_until_complete(want_item_url(loop, links, name, color))
            next_links = []
            url = ''
            for s in data:
                if s in links:
                    next_links += [s]
                else:
                    url = s
            if url:
                loop.close()
                return url
            else:
                do_task(next_links, name, color)
        return do_task(links, name, color)


global start
start = time.time()
Test = Test()
want_url = Test.non_req_url('accessories', 'Crew Socks', 'White')
print(want_url)
time_of_script = time.time() - start
print('実行時間：{}'.format(time_of_script))
```

## 追記9/11

> この条件で timeout したものを続けて再帰処理を行うことに意味があるのか疑問に感じます。

限定商品の販売日とかはサイトが重くなるので、その中でもなるべく早い処理を行えないかと思い考えました。

実際にこの処理を追加すると普段の時でも倍の時間がかかるようになってしまいました。これはif文、try文やfor文の内包表記を辞めてしまった事によるのでしょうか？それとも何か再帰にする事で通常の状態で無駄な処理を行なっているのでしょうか？

depthの制限を追加したら速度が改善しました。
普通にサイトアクセス出来る時でも再帰的な処理が多重に行われているのでしょうか？通常の状態でも多重に再帰処理が行われているのは少し無駄に感じてしまいます。

> とするのであれば data にはヒットした url とヒットできなかった場合の link を混在して使う前提になっているのではありませんか？
> （あまり気持ち良い設計ではないですね）

素人なので気持ちの良い設計については分からないですが、`loop.run.until()`の中にある処理を触るのはまだ知識不足で難しそうと判断したため返ってきた値を仕分けすれば良いと考えてしまいました。

個人的には`loop.run.until()`より下のコードで`if`文を多用しているのでもう少しスッキリ出来ないかなとか考えてしまいます。

** 9/21 結果報告

```
再帰の回数確認depth:  10
Stripe Appliqué S/S Top
Navy
Stripe Appliqué S/S Top
Slate
商品ページがひらけない
商品ページがひらけない
S/S Pocket Tee
Heather Coral
Textured Small Box Sweater
Black
S/S Pocket Tee
Black
商品ページがひらけない
商品ページがひらけない
商品ページがひらけない
Small Box Tee
Digi Floral
Small Box Tee
Fluorescent Yellow
Small Box Tee
Heather Grey
商品ページがひらけない
Small Box Tee
Rust

再帰の回数確認depth:  9
再帰の回数確認depth:  8
再帰の回数確認depth:  7
再帰の回数確認depth:  6
再帰の回数確認depth:  5
再帰の回数確認depth:  4
再帰の回数確認depth:  3
再帰の回数確認depth:  2
再帰の回数確認depth:  1
再帰の回数確認depth:  0
```

いくつか取得出来ないページあるにも関わらず、再帰処理で取得する様子が見られませんでした。イメージだと再帰回数の確認9と8の間に取得出来なかったページを再び巡回して取得出来た、出来ないが表示されても良さそうなのですが、やはり再帰処理は上手く行われていないのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問内容が移り変わってきているので、新たに別の質問として立てた方が良いと思われます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

timeout=(3.0, 7.5)
となると connect timeout が 3秒 read timeout が 7.5 秒ですが、この条件で timeout したものを続けて再帰処理を行うことに意味があるのか疑問に感じます。

```
for s in data:
    if s in links:
    next_links += [s]
else:
    url = s
```

とするのであれば data にはヒットした url とヒットできなかった場合の link を混在して使う前提になっているのではありませんか？
（あまり気持ち良い設計ではないですね）

最も大きな問題は

```
else:
    url = s
```

としているため data の最後が None の場合は url が None となって永遠に再帰処理を呼び出しますね。

で期待するコードと思われる内容を提示します。

```
    def __init__(self):
        #self.links = []   # 使用していない
        pass

    # ...
    def search_item(self, link, name, color):
        # ...
        except Timeout:
            print('商品ページがひらけない')
            #return url
            return link  # 返したいのは link

    def search_item(self, link, name, color):
        # 再帰のリミット回数を設ける
        def do_task(links, name, color, depth):   # depth 追加
            if depth <= 0:                        # 追加
                return                            # 追加
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = loop.run_until_complete(want_item_url(loop, links, name, color))
            next_links = []
            url = ''
            for s in data:
                if s in links:
                    next_links += [s]
                #else:                            # 削除
                elif s:                           # 追加
                    url = s
                    break
            if url:
                loop.close()
                return url
            else:
                # 2020/09/21 do_task の前に return 追記
                return do_task(next_links, name, color, depth - 1)  # depth - 1 追加
        return do_task(links, name, color, 10)    # 10 depth 指定
```

### 追記9/11 の回答

> 実際にこの処理を追加すると普段の時でも倍の時間がかかるようになってしまいました。これはif文、try文やfor文の内包表記を辞めてしまった事によるのでしょうか？それとも何か再帰にする事で通常の状態で無駄な処理を行なっているのでしょうか？

性能については事実を把握すべきです。
time.time() を使用して処理毎の経過時間を調べて元のコードの時間と再帰版の時間を比較しましょう。

> depthの制限を追加したら速度が改善しました。
> 普通にサイトアクセス出来る時でも再帰的な処理が多重に行われているのでしょうか？通常の状態でも多重に再帰処理が行われているのは少し無駄に感じてしまいます。

url が取得できれば再帰処理は動かないコードにしています。
適宜 ptint('depth: ', depth) を入れて再帰が動作しているか確認しましょう。

Comment: エラーの原因はありがとうございます。少し質問を追加したので見ていただけないでしょうか？`return url`が`return link`だったんだと思います。あれでは`https://www.supremenewyork.com`が数珠つなぎになっていきますね。

Comment: 返信がとても遅くなり申し訳ありません。`depth`の回数確認を行うために`def do task...`の直下に`ptint('depth: ', depth)`を記述したのですが、タイムアウトしない時も10と表示されます。おそらく通常の状態でも10回再帰処理が行われている事が考えられます。

Comment: 最初に do_task(links, name, color, 10) で呼び出して関数内で do_task(next_links, name, color, depth - 1) で再帰呼び出しです。１０とだけ表示されるということは１回しか実行していないということです。２回以上呼び出す場合は、呼び出し毎に１つずつ小さい depth が表示されるコードになります。

Comment: すいません。とても早とちりしていました。10から少なくなっていくんでした。明日これで試して結果を報告します。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 結果の報告を追記しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 私が提示したコードをよく見てください。
'商品ページがひらけない'場合の return url を return link に書き変えなければ再帰処理は必ず失敗します。
ただ、修正しても timeout=(3.0, 7.5) で取得できなかったものが次のアクセスで取得できる可能性は低いのではありませんか？

Comment: `return link`変更してテストを行いました。質問の内容、コード（キャンセル処理追加のため）も上記のものと変わってきたので新しく質問を立てました。すいません。よろしくお願いします。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70582/%e9%9d%9e%e5%90%8c%e6%9c%9f%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8brequests%e3%81%8c%e3%82%bf%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a0%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e8%b5%b7%e3%81%93%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%99%82-%e5%86%8d%e5%b8%b0%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84