# seleniumとasyncioの組み合わせでquitしてもプロセスが残ってしまう

Tags: python, selenium, 非同期

seleniumとasyncioを組み合わせて複数のdriverを非同期で走らせています。
普通にdriverを立ち上げてquitする分にはプロセスが残らないのですが、Ctrl-Cで強制終了するとプロセスが残ってしまいます。
うまくプロセスをkillする方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。

環境:
Raspberry Pi OS

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Python 3.9.2

ソースコード:
コメントアウトの部分を外して終了を待てばうまくkillされます。
Ctrl-Cで強制終了するとexceptブロックを通過しているはずなのにプロセスが残ってしまいます。

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import urllib3
import asyncio

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

def fetch_page():
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver"), options=options)
        url = "https://www.google.com/"
        while True:
            driver.get(url)
            #driver.quit()
            #break
    except urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError:
        driver.quit()

async def main():
    coros = [asyncio.to_thread(fetch_page) for _ in range(3)]
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(coro) for coro in coros]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: もしかしたら、この辺の記事が何か参考になるかも。[Python asyncioでのシグナルハンドリングの基本と応用](https://ittrip.xyz/python/asyncio-signal-handling), [Pythonのasyncioでgraceful shutdown](https://qiita.com/yota-p/items/f288dd8b4b10bad712c1), [Pythonでasyncioの非同期処理を実行中にシグナルハンドラが実行された場合、非同期処理は処理を一時的に停止するか？](https://blog.symdon.info/posts/1619229765/), [How to gracefully terminate an asyncio script with Ctrl-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48562893/9014308), [How to handle Ctrl-C on asyncio server and client programs](https://discuss.python.org/t/how-to-handle-ctrl-c-on-asyncio-server-and-client-programs/27261)

Comment: あるいはこのサイトでもseleniumではないですがrequestsで類似と思われる記事があるようです。[Pythonのrequests処理を非同期にしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70112/26370)

Answer (score 0):

kunifさん、参考サイトを教えていただきありがとうございます。

signalモジュールを使う方法やpsutilモジュールで子プロセスを再起的にkillする方法を試しましたが、上手く行く場合と失敗する場合がありなかなか成功しませんでした。

当初の目的のCtrl-cで終了する方法はできなかったのですが、enterを押して終了する方法を思いつき何とか目的は達成できました。

もしCtrl-cでkillする方法が分かる方いましたら回答お待ちしています。

一応現時点のコードです。

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import asyncio

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

stop = False

def fetch_page():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver"), options=options)
    url = "https://www.google.com/"
    while True:
        driver.get(url)
        if stop:
            driver.quit()
            break

def wait_enter():
    global stop
    input()
    stop = True

async def main():
    coros = [asyncio.to_thread(fetch_page) for _ in range(3)]
    coros.append(asyncio.to_thread(wait_enter))
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(coro) for coro in coros]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```